# i'm trying to remove duplicate from big data(4919214, 2 )but got this error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, duplicates, bigdata

here is shape of dataframe

```
df.head()
```

when i try to remove duplicates getting this error and i also try to replace [ this from column 'coordinates' please help me out in this

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='coordinates')
```

this is the error i'm getting continuously

```
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-25-f4aacff1447d> in <module>
    ----> 1 df.drop_duplicates(subset='coordinates')
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in drop_duplicates(self, subset, keep, inplace, ignore_index)
       5269         inplace = validate_bool_kwarg(inplace, "inplace")
       5270         ignore_index = validate_bool_kwarg(ignore_index, "ignore_index")
    -> 5271         duplicated = self.duplicated(subset, keep=keep)
       5272 
       5273         result = self[-duplicated]
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in duplicated(self, subset, keep)
       5406 
       5407         vals = (col.values for name, col in self.items() if name in subset)
    -> 5408         labels, shape = map(list, zip(*map(f, vals)))
       5409 
       5410         ids = get_group_index(labels, shape, sort=False, xnull=False)
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in f(vals)
       5380 
       5381         def f(vals):
    -> 5382             labels, shape = algorithms.factorize(
       5383                 vals, size_hint=min(len(self), SIZE_HINT_LIMIT)
       5384             )
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py in factorize(values, sort, na_sentinel, size_hint)
        720             na_value = None
        721 
    --> 722         codes, uniques = factorize_array(
        723             values, na_sentinel=na_sentinel, size_hint=size_hint, na_value=na_value
        724         )
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py in factorize_array(values, na_sentinel, size_hint, na_value, mask)
        526 
        527     table = hash_klass(size_hint or len(values))
    --> 528     uniques, codes = table.factorize(
        529         values, na_sentinel=na_sentinel, na_value=na_value, mask=mask
        530     )
    
    pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.factorize()
    
    pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable._unique()
    
    TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your coordinates column is a list, which you cannot use drop_duplicates on.

One approach is to treat it as a string, however, note that different ordering in the list will treat them as unique values.

```
df['coordinates'] = df.coordinates.astype('string')

# This will treat [1, 2] and [2, 1] as unique values.
df.drop_duplicates(subset='coordinates')

# Convert it back to a list
df['coordinates'] = df.coordinates.apply(eval)
```

---

Note that eval is not a secure function and may leave you vulnerable to [code injection](https://medium.com/swlh/hacking-python-applications-5d4cd541b3f1).

---